botocore package not found though installed in linux ec2
I have installed python package boto and botocore using pip on linux ec2 instance. But I am not finding these packages under /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/. If I do "pip show botocore" and "pip show boto". It shows below :
Name: boto
Version: 2.49.0
Summary: Amazon Web Services Library
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto/
Author: Mitch Garnaat
Author-email: mitch@garnaat.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

Name: botocore
Version: 1.34.108
Summary: Low-level, data-driven core of boto 3.
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/botocore
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email:
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/propel/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: jmespath, python-dateutil, urllib3
Required-by: boto3, s3transfer

Because of this my ansible script is failing and is throwing below error:
\"msg\": \"Failed to import the required Python library (botocore or boto3) on ip-10-84-88-104.us-east-2.compute.internal's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location.

Please help me how to fix this.
Thanks,
PNV
I uninstalled and installed again. Not sure what to do further. No luck

Side-note: You should install boto3 rather than boto.
